# gnuplot - how can I lag a series?

Tags: gnuplot, lag

I have 2 series in a file and I wish to lag one so that I can do a scatter plot?

Preferably, I would like to do this in a function like:

```
f(x,y) = x*(y-previous(y))
```

Is there a way to do this?

or even

```
plot "mydata.txt" u 3:(lagged($3))
```

Would help

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server 
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project 
Release: 1.13.3.0 
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 LskyHome2 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39 i686 
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (WoW64) 
Package: version 1.13.3-1 built 2013-03-09
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function:

```
lag(x) = ($0 == 0) ? (val1 = x, 0) : (val2 = val1, val1 = x, val1-val2)
```

This returns the difference between each point and the one before, and returns 0 if it is the first data point.  `$0` is the line-number pseudocolumn; functions can see columns from a datafile if they are called from within a plot command.

You can use it like

```
plot 'mydata.txt' u 3:(lag($3))
```

Comment: I get this error: gnuplot> lag(x) = ($0 == 0) ? (val1 = x, 0) : (val2 = val1, val1 = x, val1-val2)

                                    ^
         ')' expected

Comment: Hmm.  I don't get an error running that command.  Do you get the error defining the function or using it?  Which version of gnuplot/platform are you using?

Comment: I added system details to question

Comment: Thanks, it would still be useful information to know the gnuplot version.  I get the same error running an old version (4.2.6) but not when I use a newer version (4.6.1 or 4.7.0).  You can try updating gnuplot to see if that helps.

Comment: gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0. I don't know how to get newer version. I use cygwin setup.exe - and that doesn't give choices...

Comment: Hmm.  You might try looking at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/development/index.html for some info on building from source.  Also at the bottom of that page is a link to some binaries for Windows of 4.7.0, but those are for MinGW.